# Google Sheets script won't run with trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code runs successfully when executed manually but fails to run on a day trigger. How do I fix this issue?

```
function Add100Videos() {

// get current sheet and tabs
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var current = ss.getSheetByName('100NOW');
var database = ss.getSheetByName('ADD');

// count rows to snap
var current_rows = current.getLastRow();
var database_rows = database.getLastRow() + 1;
var database_rows_new = current_rows + database_rows - 2;
var rows_new = current.getRange("A2:J" + current_rows).getValues();

// snap rows, can run this on a trigger to be timed
database.getRange("A" + database_rows + ":J" + database_rows_new).setValues(rows_new);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Add100Videos() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh1_rows = sh1.getLastRow();
  var sh2_rows = sh2.getLastRow() + 1;
  var sh2_rows_new = sh1_rows + sh2_rows - 2;
  var rows_new = sh1.getRange("A2:J" + sh1_rows).getValues();
  sh2.getRange("A" + sh2_rows + ":J" + sh2_rows_new).setValues(rows_new);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();//this will write all of the data into the visible user interface
}
```